# ImportError: no module named contact.forms

Tags: django

according to Djangobook.com chapter7 I'm trying to import ContactForm from contact.forms but I faced this:

> > > from contact.forms import ContactForm
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named contact.forms

as much as I struggled and searched find nothing. I would appreciate your advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the relative paths in Django Book when I went through. Normally just check that the forms file is in the same folder as the folder you are working on. Otherwise try `appname.contact.forms` or just `forms`. Something like that. If you could post the file branching of your project that would help too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. since I had not added a separate directory for contact from last chapter ( it has been told as optional) I was still working in main directory of project. I added it with a __init__.py in it and it worked.